# OneToMany in MappedSuperclass

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I was trying to use `@MappedSuperclass` to share the same table between two entities following this article here ([How to map multiple JPA entities to one database table with Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/map-multiple-jpa-entities-one-table-hibernate/)),

So I have these 3 classes:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class UserDao {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    var username: String? = null

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    var groups: Set<GroupDao>? = null

}
```

then:

```
@Entity(name = "basic_user_auth")
@Table(name = "users")
class BasicUserDao : UserDao() {
}
```

and:

```
@Entity(name = "full_auth_user")
@Table(name = "users")
class FullUserDao : UserDao() {

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    var profileJpa: ProfileDao? = null
}
```

what I was trying is to save some queries overhead of loading the user profile when its not needed, but now when i try to run the app i get the following error:

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [full_auth_user_username" of relation "users_groups];
```

not sure why Hibernate creates this relation since they both share the same table.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you don't share types on the entity level. Sharing a one-to-many association will probably not work as you expect with respect to flushing/synchronization when multiple such entities are involved. IMO you should try out a DTO approach instead.

I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(User.class)
public interface BasicUserDao {
    @IdMapping
    String getUsername();
    Set<GroupDao> getRoles();

    @EntityView(Group.class)
    interface GroupDao {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
@EntityView(User.class)
public interface FullUserDao extends BasicUserDao {
    @Mapping("profileJpa")
    ProfileDao getProfile();

    @EntityView(Profile.class)
    interface ProfileDao {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }

}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`BasicUserDao a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, BasicUserDao.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository {
    List<BasicUserDao> findAll();
}
```

The best thing about it is, that it will only fetch the data that is actually needed.